# How to prove that $\oint_{C} q[\vec{v}\times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{r}=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics

How to prove that $\oint_C q[\vec{v}\times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{r}=0$ rigorously, where $q[\vec{v}\times \vec{B}]$ is the magnetic force acting on a positive change q, $\vec{v}$ is the velocity, and $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field. I can prove it qualitatively by saying that $\vec{v}$ is is in the same direction as d$\vec{r}$, and since $\vec{v}\times \vec{B}$ is normal to $\vec{v}$, therefore to d$\vec{r}$, then $q[\vec{v}\times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{r}=0$ and consequently $\oint_C q[\vec{v}\times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{r}=0$, but this doesn't look like a rigorous proof to me, so how can I prove it rigorously?

Comment: I don’t have the formal definition of the contour integral in front of me, but I’m almost sure that there’s a suitable proof which lies along these lines, rewriting the contour integral as an integral in terms of $t$ and then showing that $(\vec{r}’ \times \vec{B}) \cdot \vec{r}’ = 0.$

Comment: What makes $\vec v$ tangent to the path? You have not provided enough detail or context. I’m guessing $\vec v$ is the velocity of the charged particle. But once you write the definition of a line integral and specify the details, yes, it’s obvious.

Comment: The integral is path independent, so it doesn't matter which path one take to evaluate the integral

Comment: Your proof that $\vec{v}$ is tangent to $d\vec{r}$ is rigorous. When you write out the definition of the line integral you will notice that $d\vec{r}$ becomes $\vec{v}\,dt\,.$ Hence its scalar product with $\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ is zero as noted by the other commenters already. Not only is the integral zero for closed paths, this holds in this case for all paths. In the absence of $\vec{E}$ the Lorentz force does  not accelerate or slow down the electron. It only changes its direction. No work is done. That's what this is telling you.